# .DS_Store file in os.walk()

Tags: python, file-rename

I am trying to write a code which renames files in directory's folder and subfolders. However while reading the filenames using os.walk I always encounter the .DS_Store file (system generated file in MacOS). Any solutions to get past this?
I am using os.walk() in this manner:

```
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        # scroll_count = 1
        # panel_count = 1
        files.sort()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 11, in replace
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.DS_Store'
```

Comment: A simple `if not path.endswith('.DS_Store'):` might work. Alternatively, it's possible to disable the creation of .DS_Store files altogether, though it requires a reboot after executing the command. In that case just delete the ones currently there and it should work

Comment: The code sample you provided won't raise this error on its own.

Comment: Yea I am making manipulations to the file names in the latter part of the code. The error is raised there. Those lines of code are subject to privacy issues